# merge two dataframes with common keys and adding unique columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have read through [the pandas guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-dataframes-with-same-column-names/), especially `merge` and `join` sections, but still can not figure it out.

Basically, this is what I want to do: Let's say we have two data frames:

```
left = pd.DataFrame(
{   "key": ["K0", "K1", "K2", "K3"],
    "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
    "C": ["B0", "B1", np.nan, np.nan]})

right = pd.DataFrame(
{   "key": ["K2"],
    "A": ["A8"], 
    "D": ["D3"]})
```

I want to merge them based off on "key" and update the values, filling where necessary and replacing old values if there are any. So it should look like this:

```
   key A    C    D
0  K0  A0   B0  NaN
1  K1  A1   B1  NaN
2  K2  A8  NaN  D3
3  K3  A3  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first) with `set_index` to accomplish your goal here.

```
right.set_index('key').combine_first(left.set_index('key')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  key   A    C    D
0  K0  A0   B0  NaN
1  K1  A1   B1  NaN
2  K2  A8  NaN   D3
3  K3  A3  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Dataframe "left" needs to be replaced by common values of dataframe "right". This solution does not update values of dataframe "left". For example, A2 needs to be replaced by A8 which comes from "right" dataframe.

Comment: @user18083922 Yep, just noticed that. Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: Use right.combine_first(left) to keep the right values first then update with left.